# Chrome webGL stopped working

Tags: linux, google-chrome, fedora

Before a month, my webgl in chrome stopped working. In firefox, it works as expected, in chrome not. What's the problem? How to enable it?

Comment: Look here: http://superuser.com/questions/836832/how-can-i-enable-webgl-in-my-browser